Building an app to log which group is at which project everyday. Trying to get the information to save to Excel
New to building apps with Tkinter and Python.
The purpose of this app is to store data in an excel worksheet. Date/Who/Where are the 3 data points i want to get saved in excel. i was following an example from a website but i am stuck with integrating the saving to excel.
the submit button isnt working, nothing is getting saved on excel and i even put the workbook in the same folder as the .py for the app but i cannot find how to properly instruct the app to save to the specific file path. I also have googled but cant find how to add today's date to be saved every time the submit button is pressed
#Example Code
import openpyxl
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def register():
 # Get the user input from the form
 first_name = first_name_entry.get()
 Last_name = Last_name_entry.get()
 email = email_entry.get()
 Mobile = Mobile_entry.get()

 # Create a new row with the user input
 new_row = [first_name, Last_name, email,Mobile]

 # Append the new row to the Excel sheet
 workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("registration_data.xlsx")
 sheet = workbook.active
 sheet.append(new_row)
 workbook.save("registration_data.xlsx")
 messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Registration successful!")


# Create the main tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title("Registration Form")
root.geometry('300x300')

# Create labels and entry fields for each input
first_name_label = Label(root, text="First Name:")
first_name_label.pack()
first_name_entry = Entry(root)
first_name_entry.pack()

Last_name_label = Label(root, text="Last Name:")
Last_name_label.pack()
Last_name_entry = Entry(root) 
Last_name_entry.pack()

email_label = Label(root, text="Email:")
email_label.pack()
email_entry = Entry(root)
email_entry.pack()

Mobile_label = Label(root, text="Mobile:")
Mobile_label.pack()
Mobile_entry = Entry(root)
Mobile_entry.pack()



register_button = Button(root, text="Register", command=register)
register_button.pack()

root.mainloop()


#My code up to this point

import openpyxl
from tkinter import \*
from tkinter import messagebox

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Crew Tracker")
ws.geometry('300x300')

nameLb1 = Label(ws, text="Select Crew")
nameLb1.grid(row=0, column=0)

nameLb2 = Label(ws, text="Select Site Number")
nameLb2.grid(row=1, column=0)

nameLb3 = Label(ws, text="Enter Crew")
nameLb3.grid(row=3, column=0)

nameLb3_entry = Entry(ws)
nameLb3_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

nameLb4 = Label(ws, text="Enter Site Number")
nameLb4.grid(row=2, column=0)

nameLb4_entry = Entry(ws)
nameLb4_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

site_number = StringVar()
site_number.set("Site Number")

site = OptionMenu(ws,site_number, "OK1908", "HX4735", "OK1598", "HX4947")
site.grid(row=1, column=1)

Crew = StringVar()
Crew.set("Crew")

Crews = OptionMenu(ws,Crew, "#1 Ray", "#2 Carlos", "#3 Raul", "#4 Jorge")
Crews.grid(row=0, column=1)

new_row = \[nameLb3_entry, nameLb4_entry\]

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("Crew_tracker\_#1.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
workbook.save("Crew_tracker\_#1.xlsx")

def Submit():

    nameLb3_entry.get()
    nameLb4_entry.get()

Submit_button = Button(ws, text="Submit", command=Submit)
Submit_button.grid(row=4, column=1)

messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Submittal Successful")

ws.mainloop()


In the example code, getting the data from the entries and saving data to a file is done inside a function that runs when the button is clicked. Do the same in the Submit function.

It is so obvious that the Submit() function does not have any code on saving data to Excel file.
